# Java: Implement Setter Method With Subclass of Parameter Type?

Tags: java

I have two Interface here:

```
public interface Configuration {

}

public abstract interface Configurable {

    public Configurable setConfig(Configuration config);

}
```

And when one of my implementation tries to override the `setConfig()`method, the compiler will complain that is not overriding a super class method.

```
// This is not correct.
@Override
public SubConfigurable setConfig(SubConfiguration config) {
    this.config = config;
    return this;
}
```

I understand that I could always pass in a Configuration object and cast down to its real type but I am wondering if there is better way to target this. Or maybe I am just in a wrong design approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think that's the *actual* code. Did you mean `SubConfiguration` by chance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to make the interface generic, specifying the type of configuration with a generic type parameter, with an upper bound.

```
public interface Configurable<C extends Configuration> {
    public Configurable setConfig(C config);
}
```

Then the subclass can specify which `Configuration` is required.

```
public class SubConfigurable implements Configurable<SubConfigurable> {

    @Override
    public SubConfigurable setConfig(SubConfiguration config) {
        this.config = config;
        return this;
    }
}
```

This is not necessary for the return type, because Java return types are covariant.  A subclass can return a subtype of the original method and still override that original method.  Parameter types in overriding methods are not covariant, but using generics in this way is a valid solution.

Comment: And I think `Configurable#setConfig` should then be declared to return a `Configurable<C>` to work completely generically.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thx. Actually I tried the other way around (Configuration<T extends Configurable>) and it did not work. I think I still need to understand generic more.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Java Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html). Also java interface does not have to implicitly be declared as abstract, it is already abstract.